# How to load xml to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in java without errors?

Tags: java, spring

I have xml file to java to configure i can't load this that files in beans javas

main.java:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
PDF2HTMLService service = appContext.getBean(PDF2HTMLService.class);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be converted to org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at pdf2html.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

how can i solve this problems...

XML FILE:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="pdf2html" />

</beans>
```

Comment: What spring dependencies are you using?

Comment: Also please show your imports in the code

Comment: what are the versions of spring jars you are using?

Comment: org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar, org.springframework.beans_3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, external jar,

Comment: As @geoand said, please show us your imports.

Comment: import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

Comment: Are you using any weird aspects?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext implements ApplicationContext`. Might be a classpath issue.

The `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is loaded from one jar, but `ApplicationContext` from another and they aren't compatible by versions.

Check you classpath for duplication of `spring-context-[VERSION].jar`

Comment: All Spring jar should be in the same varsion and be sure that there is no other copies of them. I mean in differnt versions. E.g. `org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar, org.springframework.beans_3.0.5.RELEASE.jar` is bad. They both should be at least 3.0.5. However it isn't the last version: http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Comment: k k, I have a xml file how can solve this two steps ?

Comment: Which xml? Which steps? You have bytecode incompatibility. The different versions of the same class.